# Trying to execute postgres function using Execute

Tags: postgresql-9.2

```
        CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION chkfunction(schemaname text, state text, wallmaterial text, roofmaterial text)
            RETURNS text AS
            $BODY$   
            DECLARE 
            tblinclusion text;

        BEGIN


            execute'if (SELECT exists( select schema_name FROM information_schema.schemata WHERE schema_name = '||$1 ||') )
            then
            tblinclusion:="yes";
            return tblinclusion;
            else
            tblinclusion:="no";
            return tblinclusion;'
            Using schemaname;
        END;
        $BODY$
        LANGUAGE plpgsql
```

But it is throwing error:

```
syntax error at or near "if"
LINE 1: if (SELECT exists( select schema_name FROM information_schem...
```

Answer (score 0):

First, since you appear to be new to Stackoverflow, here's a few etiquette and posting tips:

- Always include relevant version information. Here, you probably want to include PostgreSQL's version info
- Give a brief, concise description of what you want to do
- Include any relevant source code (which you did... nice job)
- Include any errors (which you did... again, nice job)
- Explain what you want the result to be
- Follow up and mark an answer.  For a lot of people, if you don't give credit for a correct answer, they won't help you.  Just a tip.

Since you didn't do all of the above, I'm left guessing, so I'm making some assumptions based on your code.  It seems like you want to return the text 'yes' if a schema exists and 'no' if the schema doesn't.  If that is not your desire, please update the question.  If correct, it seems like following should work for you:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION chkfunction2(schemaname text)
RETURNS text AS
$BODY$   
DECLARE 
BEGIN

    PERFORM schema_name FROM information_schema.schemata WHERE schema_name = $1; 

    IF FOUND THEN
        RETURN 'yes';
    ELSE
        RETURN 'no';
    END IF;

END;
$BODY$
LANGUAGE plpgsql
```

Note: I don't see any need for the extra variables or declares, so I've left them out.  Also, please note that my solution was develop and tested with PostgreSQL 9.1

Welcome to StackOverflow!

Comment: sir Thanks for the tips, I will keep in mind, 
1. I am checking whether the schema name and table name present in tha databse.

2. the schema and table name are passing as parameters,

also if these are not present i want to create a new schema and table from the parameter passed and th eresult of sub query

Comment: @Anusha I recommend you edit you question to include this information.